# Need help on the general formula for the Taylor series of $\frac{2x}{e^{2x}-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series

I need help on deriving the general formula for the Taylor series of $\frac{2x}{e^{2x}-1}$

It is known that the series for $\dfrac{x}{e^{x}-1}$ is: $$\dfrac{x}{e^{x}-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{B_nx^{n}}{n!}$$

So the question is whether the series for $\frac{2x}{e^{2x}-1}$ is:

$$\frac{2x}{e^{2x}-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{B_n(2x)^{n}}{n!}\tag{1}$$

or

$$\frac{2x}{e^{2x}-1}=2\left(\dfrac{x}{e^{2x}-1}\right)=2\left(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{B_n(2x)^{n}}{n!}\right)\tag{2}$$

So which series is the correct representation for $\frac{2x}{e^{2x}-1}$? $(1)$ or $(2)$

I suspect that it must be $(2)$, because if it is $(1)$, how does one represent the series for $\dfrac{3x}{e^{2x}-1}$

Comment: For your last question, note that $$\dfrac{3x}{e^{2x}-1}=\dfrac32\dfrac{2x}{e^{2x}-1}.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make the substitution $u=2x$, it’s clear that

$$\frac{2x}{e^{2x}-1}=\frac{u}{e^u-1}=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{B_nu^n}{n!}=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{B_n(2x)^n}{n!}\,.$$

And from that we get

$$\frac{3x}{e^{2x}-1}=\frac32\cdot\frac{2x}{e^{2x}-1}=\frac32\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{B_n(2x)^n}{n!}\,.$$

Comment: I see, a clever trick for $\dfrac{3x}{e^{2x}-1}$